# Equation of infinitesimal ring when finding $ \vec{E}$ of a disc?

Tags: electric-fields, charge, integration, calculus, coulombs-law

When trying to find the electric field created by a uniformly charged disc at a point P on axis of the disc, it can be done by integration.

[image]

We start by finding the electric field dE created by each infinitesimal disc of thickness da, as shown in the picture.

The area of each infinitesimal ring is said to be 2*pi*a*da.

Shouldn't it be pi*(a+da)^2 -pi*a^2? Because it should be the area of the large ring of radius (a+da) minus the smaller ring inside of radius a to find the area of just the ring thickness da?

I suspect it's something to do with the expansion of what I believe it should be, because I'm not exactly sure what (da)^2 would equal? Is this the error?

Comment: Please change your post to use mathjax to display math

Comment: Imagine using $\Delta a$ instead for a moment and comparing it to $(\Delta a)^2$ as $\Delta a \to 0$. For example what if $\Delta a \sim 10^{-10}$? Then remember that differentials are infinitesimally small in comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see the image below
[image]
Here,π(da)² is eliminated because (da) is a very small element and it's square is even smaller and tends to 0.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting equations and variables. Images are not accessible to all users.

Comment: Even if (da)^2 is very small, shouldn't it strictly still be used in the integral since we are dealing with infinitesimal values anyway?

Comment: da or $\Delta$a is a very small value , suppose something like $10^{-10}$, square of which is even small => $10^{-20}$ which you can assume 0.